# php text field turns numbers into decimals

Tags: php, javascript

l need help to finish my php project.
l will like to have a text fields V1,V2,V3 and result/output to accept only decimal numbers (4 decimal place ie 0.0000) or automatically turns numbers to four decimal pace and have a read-only field generate the total sum of the 3 text fields without reloading the form.

eg
`text field v1+text field v2+text field v3=text field result`

the text field should accept on four decimal numbers or automatically turn numbers to four decimal place.

I am using the following sum function;

```
function sum() 
{
    var TotalLBCReceipts = num("TotalLBCReceipts");
    var TotalKaaseReceipts = num("TotalKaaseReceipts");
    var TakoradiToFactory = num("TakoradiToFactory2");
    var KaaseToFactory = num("KaaseToFactory2");
    var SampleResidue = num("SampleResidue");
    var Sweepings  = num("Sweepings");
    var OrganicCocoa = num("OrganicCocoa2");
    var Confiscated = num("Confiscated");
    var Cuttings = num("Cuttings");
    var r = document.getElementById("GRANDTOTAL1");

    if (r != null) 
    {
         r.value = TotalLBCReceipts + 
                   TotalKaaseReceipts + 
                   TakoradiToFactory +
                   KaaseToFactory +
                   SampleResidue +
                   Sweepings +
                   OrganicCocoa +
                   Confiscated+Cuttings;
     }
}
```

And grabbing the Values using;

```
function num(id) 
{
    var e = document.getElementById(id);

    if (e != null) 
    {
        var v = e.value;
        if (/^\d+$/.test(v)) 
        {
            return parseInt(v, 10);
        }
    }

return 0;

}
```

thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Oh you're doing homework? That's cool. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is your friend... As is StackOverflow!!

You need to use JavaScript here, perhaps as well as PHP...

**Restrict to Numbers with decimal place:**

[Restricting input to textbox: allowing only numbers and decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808184/restricting-input-to-textbox-allowing-only-numbers-and-decimal-point)

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <SCRIPT language=Javascript>
       <!--
       function isNumberKey(evt)
       {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
          if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
             return false;

          return true;
       }
       //-->
    </SCRIPT>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <INPUT id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" 
           type="text" name="txtChar">
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

**Sum Numbers with readonly field:**

[adding the text box values and display it using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131410/adding-the-text-box-values-and-display-it-using-javascript)

```
<form name="myFormName">
    <p><input type="text" name="myInputName1" value="25.3"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="myInputName2" value="14.2"></p>
</form>
<div id="total"></div>

<script type="text/javascript>

    var total = parseFloat(0, 10);

    total += parseFloat(document.myFormName.myInputName1.value, 10);
    total += parseFloat(document.myFormName.myInputName2.value, 10);

    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total is " + total;

</script>
```

**Round to 4 Decimal Places;:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7269919/1305169

```
Math.round(val*10000)/10000
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

You need to change your Code to the following;

**Your** `sum` **Function:**

```
function sum() 
{
    var TotalLBCReceipts = num("TotalLBCReceipts");
    var TotalKaaseReceipts = num("TotalKaaseReceipts");
    var TakoradiToFactory = num("TakoradiToFactory2");
    var KaaseToFactory = num("KaaseToFactory2");
    var SampleResidue = num("SampleResidue");
    var Sweepings  = num("Sweepings");
    var OrganicCocoa = num("OrganicCocoa2");
    var Confiscated = num("Confiscated");
    var Cuttings = num("Cuttings");
    var r = document.getElementById("GRANDTOTAL1");

    if (r != null) 
    {
         r.value = Math.round((
                       TotalLBCReceipts + 
                       TotalKaaseReceipts + 
                       TakoradiToFactory +
                       KaaseToFactory +
                       SampleResidue +
                       Sweepings +
                       OrganicCocoa +
                       Confiscated +
                       Cuttings) * 10000) / 10000;
     }
}
```

**And your** `num` **function:**

```
function num(id) 
{
    var e = document.getElementById(id);

    if (e != null) 
    {
        return Math.round(e.value*10000)/10000;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can probably just return the plain number from the `num` Function, however I show it here for completeness!

Comment: thanks very much. Restrict to Numbers with decimal place worked but my totals text field can not calculate for decimal.

Comment: l will like to put the original codes on the answer section so that u see what l actually went

Comment: Yeah, please post what you have tried so far, and we can have a look!

Comment: PGallagher, am trying to send u my codes but having difficulties doing that. is too long for the comment section. what should l do

Comment: I've editted your original post to include the relevant problem code, and editted my code with the fix!

Comment: But how do l do that for sub totals

Comment: HI Benson, If you could accept the answer, and create a new question for your new question, I'm sure it would be answered quickly!

Comment: Peter, l accept ur answer, mean while l ve found my way through for the sub totals. l will let u know if there are any other issues. thank you very much for the help. l appreciate it a lot.

Comment: No probs Benson! Glad I could help!